# How to manage file path when accessing from different directory location?

Tags: html, jsp, file-structure

I have few web pages sitting in different directories and my goal is to have some sort of organized structure so that I can access to js or css files without hardcoding the path.

For instance, the directory structure is:

```
root --- js --- some.js
      |
      |--css --- some.css
      |
      |---pages ---- main.jsp
      |
      |---other----foo---- foo.jsp
                 |
                 |--bar --- bar.jsp
```

Then main.jsp and foo.jsp tries to reference some.js but has to have different path.

```
( main.jsp )

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/some.js"></script>

( foo.jsp)

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/some.js"></script>
```

This is not ideal if I want to change the location of main.jsp or foo.jsp, I have to come back to each files and change the path manually.

I am thinking to have factory class that has full path for each files so that it would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=<% Factory.getFullPath(some.js) %> ></script>
```

In this case, I can still move files freely and not have to come back to each file.

Can I get some opinion to my approach? Is there other way to solve this?

Comment: Can't you use an path relative to the root? i.e. /js/some.js ? Then it's relative to the domain and doesn't matter what (sub)directory you're calling it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a context-relative path. It will make the path absolute to the domain root. You can obtain the context path by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29). In JSP, the `HttpServletRequest` is available by [`${pageContext.request}`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getRequest%28%29).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/some.js"></script>
```

*(the `contextPath` itself already starts with a `/`, so you don't need to prefix it yourself)*

You can also set it using the [HTML `<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag so that *every* relative URL in the page becomes relative to it. This way you don't need to copy `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` over all the place.

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></base>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/some.js"></script>
```

This has however one caveat: anchors, like `<a href="#foo">` will also become relative to it. You need to take this into account as well if you go for this.

#### See also:

- [Is is recommended to use `<base>` tag in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Answer (score 1):

mm i'm not really sure if a factory is the most appropriate way to do this, maybe it will work.. i remember that for that i used an interface where i implemented some constants including the JS and CSS folder path

```
public interface Configuration {
   public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
   public static final String CSS_URL = SERVER_URL + "css/";
   public static final String JS_URL = SERVER_URL + "js/";
}
```

and then i'd have to import this interface in the servlet and call it like this:

```
...src="<% Configuration.JS_URL %>some.js" />..
```

that way if you change your folders name or path. you'll only have to change the configuration